# C# char calculation problem

Tags: c#

Im trying to do a permutation. of five in this case, so 5,4,3,2,1 . Eventually I want it to permute up to 100 which can be stored in my intX class. the calculation is fine, but I want to add up all individual numbers of the output, using the script below.

so 5! = 5x4x3x2x1 = 120 ----> 1+2+0 = 3. BUT My script below gives the output 147:

```
120
1
2
0
147
```

What am I doing wrong? I allready tried all converts, I started with just using the string[pointer] thingy, I tried different arrays etc.. but it all keeps coming up with 147. Is it some kind of representation thing?

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IntX total=1;
        IntX totalsum = 0;
        int perm = 5;
        for (int i = perm; i > 0; i--)
        {
            total = total * i;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(total);

        string answerstring = Convert.ToString(total);
        char[] answerArray = answerstring.ToArray();
        for (int x = 0; x < answerArray.Length; x++)
        {
            totalsum += Convert.ToInt32(answerArray[x]);
            Console.WriteLine(answerArray[x]);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(totalsum);
    }
```

Comment: total = total * i;  can be written like  total *= i;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is the way you are converting your answerArray elements back to numbers

```
Convert.ToInt32(answerArray[x])
```

The above line takes the char `1` and converts it to an int. This is not the same as parsing it as an int. 1 is ascii character 49 so internally the char has an int representation of 49 and so that is what it is converted to (since this is just trying to do a type conversion rather than any kind of processing)

Similarly 2 = 50 and 0 = 48 so you get the total of 147.

What you want to do is use Integer.Parse to parse strings as numbers. I believe it should implicitly convert the char to a string before parsing it.

So your loop would be:

```
    for (int x = 0; x < answerArray.Length; x++)
    {
        totalsum += int.Parse(answerArray[x].ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(answerArray[x]);
    }
```

You can also do it the way others suggested with subtracting chars. This works because the ascii value of 1 is 1 higher than the ascii value for 0. 2 is 2 higher, etc.

Of course this only works with single digit chars. If you ever want to convert more than two digit numbers into int from a string you'll need `int.parse`.

For what its worth I suspect that the character subtraction method is the most efficient since it is effectively just doing some very simple type conversion and subtraction. The parse method is likely to do a lot more stuff and so be a bit more heavyweight. I dont' you will notice a performance difference though.

Comment: Ahhhh, Im new to the language... Somewhat assumed that the int that was printed was the thing Id gain when I converted it. Thanks man. super! I have to wait 6 mins to be able to answer

Comment: @Hans: the reason to remember for why that clearly can't work is that your char could be 'z' or ';' and your method wouldn't work for that. I guess it could do similar to javascript where it can convert strings to numbers in clever ways but it doesn't. Or rather it does but in totally different clever ways. :)

Answer (score 6):

The problem lies in here:

```
for (int x = 0; x < answerArray.Length; x++)
{
    //Casting char to int, not what you want!
    //totalsum += Convert.ToInt32(answerArray[x]);
    //Parsing char to int, what you do want!
    totalsum += int.Parse(answerArray[x]);
    Console.WriteLine(answerArray[x]);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of converting to an integer (which will take the ASCII character value), try using `answerArray[x] - '0'`.

Answer (score 2):

(int)'0' is not equal to 0. You should use ((int)answerArray[x] - (int)'0')

Comment: The int conversions are actually unnecessary; a char - char is implicitly an int.

Comment: char - char is implicitly an int, but not the ints they appear to be.

Comment: @FlyingStreudel: What do you mean not the ints they appear to be? `'5'-'0'` equals `5` doesn't it?

Comment: Sorry, yes. A char - char is the int you would expect. However it is important to note that subtraction is the *only* operation which is viable, as behind the scenes '5' != 5.

Answer (score 2):

Why bother changing it to a char array? You already have the information that you need.

```
while (total > 0)
{
    ones_digit = total % 10;
    totalsum += ones_digit;
    total -= ones_digit;
    total /= 10;
}
```

Comment: Good point. This would be more elegant though not strictly answering the question. :)

Answer (score 1):

Convert.ToInt32 returns the Unicode values of characters 1, 2 and 0 which are 49, 50 and 48. That's why the sum comes out as 147.